# Помощь в решении Упражнения для работы с командой grep в терминале Ubuntu

Tags: grep

Помогите решить .

Упражнение для работы с командой grep в терминале Ubuntu.

Существует файл Passwords.txt  со списком паролей.(одна строка содержит один пароль)

1. Найти все пароли состоящие из 5 символов и более.
2. Найти все пароли состоящие из не более 5 символов.
3. Найти все пароли состоящие из только из заглавных букв.
4. Найти все пароли состоящие только из цифр.
5. Найти все пароли которые начинаются с буквы и заканчиваются цифрой.
6. Найти все пароли в которых есть 3 цифры.
7. Найти все пароли которые состоят из 7 знаков, начинаются на А и заканчиваются на Z и содержат хотя бы 2 цифры.

Answer (score 0):

Данное решение не включает в себя проверку валидности паролей (писалось из соображений, что все пароли составлены корректно и не содержат запрещенных символов). Большинство решений взяты из первого ответа к данному вопросу.

Ключ `-с` гарантирует вывод количества всех записей подходящих под описание, без ключа `-с` будет выведен список всех паролей подходящих под описание.

1. `grep -E '^.{5,}$' Passwords.txt -c`
2. `grep -E '^.{1,5}$' Passwords.txt -c`
3. `grep -E '^[A-Z]*$' Passwords.txt -c`
4. `grep -E '^[0-9]*$' Passwords.txt -c`
5. `grep -E '^[A-Z,a-z].*[0-9]$' Passwords.txt -c`
6. `grep -E '^([^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*){3}$' -c`
7. `grep -E '^A.{5}Z$' Passwords.txt | grep -E '([^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*){2,}' -c`

Answer (score -1):

1. `grep -E '(\w{5,}' Passwords.txt -c`
   Параметр `-с` даст общее число найденных паролей. Без него будет выдан список паролей, отвечающих на задачу.
2. `grep -E '(\w{1,5})' Passwords.txt -c`
3. `grep '^[A-Z]*$' Passwords.txt -ca`
4. `grep '^[0-9]*$' Passwords.txt -c`
5. `grep '^[A-Z,a-z]*[0-9]$' Passwords.txt -c`
6. `grep '^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$' Passwords.txt -c`
7. `grep -Ex '^[a].{5}[z]$' Passwords.txt | grep '.[0-9].[0-9]'`

Comment: 6. если пароль 1a2b3c4d5e, не сработает ведь